# Ionic Secure Storage Try Catch

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, storage

Good day,

I am using the secure storage plugin for ionic. However, I am running into errors. This is code which I am trying, copied directly from the documentation.

```
try {
    this.secureStorage.create('my_store_name').then((storage: SecureStorageObject) => {
        storage.set('key', 'value').then(
            data => console.log(data), 
            error => console.log(error));
    });
} catch(error) {
    // alert controller code which JSON.stringify the error
}
```

However, the alert controller just shows an empty object.

How do I get the error to display what went wrong?

Comment: have you tried to log the error you get from the catch?

Comment: No not yet. I was under the impression that stringify at an alert controller should show the same details.